# How we can run cron through magento without cpanel?

Tags: crontab, cpanel

How we can run cron through magento without cpanel?

I want to run directly through the magento without using capnel.

Comment: Do you mean set up cron or just run once off?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it by **CLI**

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: I guess, "through the magento" is supposed to mean via admin panel and not in the shell. But since that's not possible, this is still the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the cron by manually www.domainame.com/cron.php. So cpanel and ssh is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without cpanel, I would recommend using a free online service like https://cron-job.org/en/ or any free online cronjob service pointed at your www.domainame.com/cron.php file.

You can set the exact time of day you want your cron job to run.

This has worked perfectly for me when i previously didnt use cpanel.